# controller.User has no claims even though Identity.Applicaton cookie is sent

Tags: asp.net-core

See also

https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/13019

After weeks, I'm flummoxed and I've exhausted the people helping me.

I had this working in .NET 4.6 and was moving it all over into a new .NET Core 2.2 project using controllers (not Razor Pages or the scaffolded identity stuff).

I've managed to get the whole Google login working and accounts and identities being created.

However, the problem is that after login, a cookie appears in Chrome and is sent on requests but the `HttpContext.User` has no claims and `HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false`.

I'm using Cosmos DB so I have custom sign-in and user manager classes and data access.

I painstakingly moved just the necessary code into a whole new .NET Core 2.2 app and then added the identity via Razor Pages scaffolding. After getting it compiling, this worked almost right off the bat, just a tweak to get the FullName claim into my user entity.

However, it suffers the same problem!

Here's my setup from my Razor Pages one. I have also tried setting a global authorization policy, too, in case that was needed to force the claims principal.

I thought that `app.UseAuthentication()` was all I need to get the cookie information to be "lifted" into a `ClaimsPrincipal`, alas no.

Please help.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ApplicationContext));
    services.AddSingleton<RepositoryFactory, AzureTableStorageRepositoryFactory>();
    services.AddTransient(typeof(AzureStorageOperationContext));
    services.AddTransient<IAccountEntityRepository, AzureAccountEntityRepository>();
    services.AddTransient<IOpenIdentityEntityRepository, AzureOpenIdentityEntityRepository>();

    services.AddIdentityCore<AspNetCoreGoogleLoginUser>()
        .AddUserStore<TimesheetsUserStore>()
        .AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AspNetCoreGoogleLoginUser>>();

    // If you want to tweak Identity cookies, they're no longer part of IdentityOptions.
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => options.LoginPath = "/Identity/Account/LogIn");
    services.AddAuthentication(authOptions =>
    {
        authOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        authOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        authOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;

    })
    .AddGoogle(googleOptions =>
    {
        this.Configuration.Bind("OAuth2:Providers:Google", googleOptions);

        googleOptions.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, "sub", "string");
    })
    .AddIdentityCookies();
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });


    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```